# Mounting a VirtualBox shared folder on boot with fstab in OpenSuse 11.3

Tags: virtualbox, opensuse, fstab

I have followed the steps found [here](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-help-here/applications/434452-virtualbox-guest-additions-how-set-shared-folder-opensuse-11-2-guest.html), however, the share is not  mounted on  boot.  The share will mount if i run 'mount -a' after booting.  Why would the share not mount on boot?

> 1 - Set up a Virtual Machine and
>   install OpenSUSE 11.2
>
> 2 - Create a shared folder on host
>   (HostFolder)
>
> 3 - Setup the shared folder in
>   Virtualbox Via the Virtual Machine
>   details or via Devices > Shared
>   Folders...
>
> 4 - Install dependencies for running
>   the Virtualbox installer You need to
>   install the right development
>   kernelpackage for your machinetype
>   (use 'zypper search -i kernel' to see
>   what's installed) sudo zypper install make gcc
>   kernel-source
>   kernel-hosttype/default-devel
>
> 5 - Run the Virtual Machine and go to
>   Devices > Guest Additions This mounts
>   an iso image in your OpenSUSE guest.
>
> 6 - Open a root terminal and run
>
> cd /usr/src/linux make oldconfig &&
>   make prepare && make scripts && make
>   dep cp
>   ../linux-obj/$HOSTTYPE/default/Module.symvers
>   . make prepare
>
> - A commenter on previously mentioned thread says this step is unnecessary
>     but it doesn't work without on my
>     system. I suggest trying step 7 first
>     and returning to step 6 if that fails.
>     *
>
> 7 - Run ./VirtualboxLinux yourhosttype
>   .run from the mounted iso image.
>
> 8 - Create shared folder in OpenSUSE
>   (GuestFolder)
>
> 9 - Test with sudo mount -t vboxsf
>   HostFolder /home/user/GuestFolder
>
> It works? Great! Let's set up the
>   system so it automounts for your
>   regular useraccount instead of
>   root-only access.
>
> 10 - Add this line to /etc/fstab
>   HostFolder /home/user/GuestFolder
>   vboxsf defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
>
> 11 - It works for me but if it still
>   doesn't automount after a reboot; sudo
>   mount -a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely familiar with the openSUSE distro, but your step 6 seems a bit much. Most modern linux distros can simply install the DKMS package, and then run the installer script from the .iso.

I am wondering if perhaps the guest additions aren't fully integrated - and they don't get activated early enough in the boot process to allow your entry in fstab to actually get recognized.

**Update:** I downloaded and installed [openSUSE-11.3-GNOME-LiveCD-i686.iso](http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/11.3/iso/openSUSE-11.3-GNOME-LiveCD-i686.iso), and the installer detected I was in VirtualBox and automatically started the Guest Additions. Also, once it had finished and booted to the desktop the Guest Additions were automatically started for me as well. There was nothing I needed to install - though I didn't test the auto-mounting once I was puzzled by the auto install of the additions.

Your question indicates you are using version 11.3, the instructions you copied and pasted indicate 11.2... What version of openSUSE distro are you testing? It is also the guest correct? What is your host OS? What version of VirtualBox are you running?

Comment: Is there a way to check this?  (props for the Tick)

Comment: This issue is no longer happening for me with newer OpenSuse builds.

Answer (score 1):

What I would consider a workaround:

Add `mount -a` to `/etc/init.d/boot.local`

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling `Auto-mount` on shared folders in VirtualBox. (Go to Settings, Shared folders and uncheck this option for every shared folder there.)

You probably don't use this feature anyway - see what it does in [VirtualBox manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sf_mount_auto).

Worked like a charm with Ubuntu in VirtualBox.